# Year wise Average days SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Today i have below problem while perform an sql query. Please find below data.

[image]

I perform SQL query on my table and get the below resulted output. i perform **Group by on ID, Name, Week, Year, Days** now i want the Days column as average of All Days based on year column. means there is multiple value of year is exist so i need Avg of Days data in all rows of DAYS for particular row. expected result as per below.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!!!
Write in comment if you have any query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OVER`:

```
SELECT
  *,
  AVG(Days) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Year, 4)) AvgDays
FROM
  Tbl
```

Note: Just grouped by year (2016)